# How to create a mini-benchmark program in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, benchmarking

I have an assignment where I need to make a benchmark program to test the performance of any processor with two sorting algorithms (an iterative one and a recursive one). The thing is my teacher told me I have to create three different programs (that is, 3 .c files), two with each sorting algorithm (both of them have to read integers from a text file separated with \n's and write the same numbers to another text file but sorted), and a benchmarking program. In the benchmark program I need to calculate the MIPs (million instructions per second) with the formula MIPs = NI/T*10^6, where NI is the number of instructions and T is the time required to execute those instructions. I have to be able to estimate the time each algorithm will take on any processor by calculating its MIPs and then solving that equation for T, like EstimatedTime = NI/MIPs*10^6.
My question is... how exactly do I measure the performance of a program with another program? I have never done something like that. I mean, I guess I can use the TIME functions in C and measure the time to execute X number of lines and stuff, but I can do that only if all 3 functions (2 sorting algorithms and 1 benchmark function) are in the same program. I don't even know how to start.

Oh and btw, I have to calculate the number of instructions by cross compiling the sorting algorithms from C to MIPS (the asm language) and counting how many instructions were used.

Any guidelines would be appreciated... I currently have these functions:

- readfile (to read text files with ints on them)
- writefile
- sorting algorithms

Comment: There should be a question somewhere..

Comment: Cross compiling to assembler would let you count the number of instructions produced by the compiler, but you'd need to work out how many times each instruction is executed somehow.

Comment: That's a question "how exactly do I measure the performance of a program with another program?". And yeah, you're right... if I have a loop, that will depend on how big is the input (how many numbers will be sorted). I hadn't thought of that lol... now I really don't know what to do haha. I guess I could count the lines outside the loop and then just  multiply the number of instructions inside the loop by the counter. For example i*24, where i is the counter (i++ and stuff) and 24 is the number of instructions being executed on each cycle.

Comment: "how exactly do I measure the performance of a program with another program?" - that's all? Well, wait some weeks, I'll have a dissertation about that ...

Comment: I don't know how to measure the execution time of a .c file with another .c file. I can only think of an include or something like that...

Comment: I think part of the assignment includes combining multiple .c files to create a single executable. You might want to review the linking step.

Answer (score 0):

How you compile the several files and link them together depends on the compiler. With GCC for example it could be something as simple as

```
gcc -O3 -g3  -W -Wall -Wextra main.c sortalog1.c sortalgo_2.c [...] sortalgo_n.c -o sortingbenchmark
```

It's not the most common way to do it, but good enough for this assignment.

If you want to count the opcodes it is probably better to compile the individual c-files individually to ASM. Do the following for every C-file you want to analyze the assembler output:

```
gcc -c -S sortalgo_n.c
```

Don't forget to put your function declarations into a common header file and include it everywhere you use them!

For benchmarking: you do know the number of ASM-operations for every C-operation and can, although it's not easy, map that count to every line of the C code. If you have that, all you have to do is to increment a counter. E.g.: if a line of C-code translates to 123 ASM opcodes you increment the counter by 123.

You can use one global variable to do so. If you use more than one thread per sorting algorithm you need to take care that the additions are atomic (Either use `_Atomic` or mutexes or whatever your OS/compiler/libraries offer).

BTW: it looks like a very exact way to measure the runtime but not every ASM-opcode runs in the same number of cycles on the CPU in the real world. No need for bothering today but you should keep it in mind for tomorrow.

Comment: The number of asm instructions per "C-operation" is not a constant, and depends on surrounding code.  The OP's method of cross-compiling for a MIPS CPU and counting instructions inside the inner loop sounds more sane than trying to extrapolate from something yourself.

Comment: I first thought something like that too, but I wouldn't know how to do it since instructions change. So yeah, I think counting instructions inside the loop is better, but I don't know how to catch the loop counter from the algorithm C file to the benchmark C file. Btw I have to benchmark the same algorithms with different -OX flags and estimate execution time on each case. I think that will also change the number of MIPS instruction translated from C...

Comment: @PeterCordes The OP wrote that the number of MIPS opcodes is known so I assumed the whole thing is a purely academic procedure. But from the comment above it seems as if it is a very realistic exercise, far from simple homework.

Comment: @sebasura: yes, optimization level will change things a lot.  O0 is usually dramatically worse than anything else, and stores everything to memory after every C statement (so you can modify variables with a debugger, for example).  Compare a simple function [on the Godbolt compiler explorer (MIPS gcc 5.4)](https://godbolt.org/g/TIBeMh) at -O3 and -O0.  Even -O1 is as good as O3 there, because there's no inlining or complex loop transformations, but O2 and O3 do matter in larger functions.

Comment: Yeah I need to actually test this on a real computer, do the whole compiling on Linux (using Docker, I'm gonna have to learn that too) and stuff. My main issue is how to count the MIPs executed in one program from another program.

Comment: @sebasura: IDK; I'd maybe try running it in a MIPS simulator (which do exist, and I assume they can count instructions).  Counting *dynamic* instruction count by hand seems impractically time-consuming for real code, unless there are only a couple loops that take all the time.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system, you can use hardware performance counters: `perf stat ./a.out` and get an accurate count of cycles, instructions, cache misses, and branch mispredicts. (other counters available, too, but those are the default ones).

This gives you the *dynamic* instruction count, counting instructions inside loops the number of times they actually ran.

Cross-compiling for MIPS and counting instructions would easily give you a static instruction count, but would require actually following how the asm works to figure out how many times each loop runs.

Comment: I know how to read MIPS so I think I might be able to do that, but if there's a tool that does it, that would be much better and in any case, it would help me to test my own calculations. I'm not familiar with Linux though... my teacher gave me this command to translate from C to MIPS but I don't know how to use it, it says that a.out doesn't exists: mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -d ./a.out

Comment: @sebasura: `a.out` is the default name for gcc's output binary if you don't use `-o`.  On Windows, gcc calls it a.exe, but on other platforms it's a.out.  Replace it with whatever you called your binary.  (i.e. if you used `gcc ... -o foo`, then it's `foo`).